# Send variable to Dash with call back in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

is it possible to have a single app.callback running on different matrix inputs?
update_figure_matrix is a function that return a figure based on input dataframe,
I would like to call this function multi[ule time with different dataframe  (matrix),
but I don't know how.

```
@app.callback(Output('tabel-matrix', 'figure'), 
              [Input('checklist', 'value')] )
def update_figure_matrix(selected_value):

    matrix_filter = matrix[matrix['First'].isin(selected_value)]
    matrix_filter = matrix_filter[matrix_filter['Second'].isin(selected_value)]
    
    figure = px.scatter(
        matrix_filter, #dataframe
        x="First", #x
        y="Second", #y
        size="Total", #bubble size
        color="Total",#bubble color
        color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plotly3, #color theme
        title="Data associated with first and second touchpoint", #chart title
    )
    figure.update_layout(
        xaxis_tickangle=30,#angle of the tick on x-axis
        title=dict(x=0.5), #set the title in center
        xaxis_tickfont=dict(size=9), #set the font for x-axis
        yaxis_tickfont=dict(size=9), #set the font for y-axis
        margin=dict(l=500, r=20, t=50, b=20), #set the margin
        paper_bgcolor="LightSteelblue", #set the background color for chart
    )    
    
    return figure



# I would like to call this code once with matrix1 (dataframe) and once with matrix2 (different dataframe) 
....
...
..


        dcc.Graph(id='tabel-matrix', #matrix = matrix1
               ),
        dcc.Graph(id='tabel-matrix', #matrix = matrix2
            
               ),
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible approaches:

1. include an additional input to your callback in order to specify which df you want to use:

```
matrices = {1: matrix1, 2: matrix2}

@app.callback(Output('table-matrix', 'figure'), 
              [Input('radioitems', 'value'), Input('checklist', 'value')])
def update_figure_matrix(matrix_no, selected_value):
    matrix = matrices[matrix_no]
    matrix_filter = matrix[matrix['First'].isin(selected_value)]
    matrix_filter = matrix_filter[matrix_filter['Second'].isin(selected_value)]
```

2. for a more generic solution you may want to consider [pattern-matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks).

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not involved callback GUI inputs, only code inputs

Comment: Can you please describe your use case a bit more? What I cannot get is a) how will the function know which is the input that must be used and b) how many figures you want to update

Comment: I want to create the same plot on different data without writing the same code twice.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from creating a separate, generic function which will create the figures based on your conditions. You can use this function inside as many callbacks as you want.

Comment: the key issue is this  - 
        dcc.Graph(id='tabel-matrix', #matrix = matrix1
               ),
        dcc.Graph(id='tabel-matrix', #matrix = matrix2
            
               ),  -- no why to reference params in the call such as the matrix2/1